# how to split on specific string in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to split string for ">" but not when >> in JavaScript.

But once I am doing a split `const words = str.split('>');` it is splitting `>>` as well.

Currently, after the split I look for "> >" and then substitute them with ">>".

How to implement it properly.

Comment: Removed python from title, since the question talks about and is tagged javascript.

Comment: Split on a regex? `str.split(/>(?!>)/g)` This will still split on the second of the two `>`s though.

Comment: Can you post the example string and expected output?

Comment: Does this help: `console.log('a>b>>c>d>>e>f;'.replaceAll('>>', '^^^').split('>').map(x => x.replace('^^^', '>>')));` (NOTE: You may use a different temporary replacement-placeholder insteadof `'^^^'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression leveraging:

- Negative lookbehind **(?>!)** causing a group to not be considered when the pattern matches before the main expression
- Negative lookahead **(?!)** causing a group to not be considered when the pattern matches after the main expression

The resulting pattern would be as follows:

```
/(?<!>)>(?!>)/
```

Using the patter to tokenize an input would lead the desired results:

```
"here>>I>am".split(/(?<!>)>(?!>)/) // => [ 'here>>I', 'am' ]
```